# Can you add apps made from (js, nodejs, express and mongodb) in a wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, mongodb, express

I already have a wordpress website. I studied web development using js, node.js, express and mongodb and build some projects. I would like to add it to my website. Is this possible or I just need to create a website without wordpress and add my projects?

Comment: To put those together, you would need a hosting provider that supports all the technologies you're using at once and allows you to somehow combine them under one domain.  Since Wordpress is its own content management system, it doesn't directly support nodejs.  So, you have to find someway to run these both in parallel and then combine the technologies yourself into what appears to be one website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WordPress** has its own **rest API** you can use WordPress API and a **frontend framework** like **Vuejs** or **React** to interact with WordPress, actually, WordPress is your backend, and the frontend framework is your frontend look at the example below:

https://52hertzcouture.com/

> this is my project frontend made with vuejs

https://backend.52hertzcouture.com/wp-login.php

> this is my project backend made with WordPress

about nodejs there are some packages like node-wpapi that can help you to
connect to wordpress rest api with nodejs as a client and do everything a
client can do, for example make posts, make pages, etc.

check out link below:

https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi

i think using wordpress as backend and a frontend framework like vuejs as
frontend is a good idea if you want to use wordpress and extend your
website.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to build another web site with a different host name. WordPress uses a venerable scheme called mod_rewrite where nodejs uses route handlers to make sense of paths. Paths are the `/section/page` parts of urls like `https://example.com/section/page`.  It will be challenging, to say the least, to integrate those two ways of handling paths.